# img lazyload requires scrolling action to work

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I'm using Arial Fleser's lazyload for images and it works perfectly, however, there's a problem whenever I decide to place certain images within something else, such as a horizontal accordion, or something that moves divs horizontally, it's like the lazyload plugin expects your image to appear in viewport via some vertical scrolling, but if your image is going to show up horizontally from, for example, css left -1500px via some jQuery function, all you end up with is the image placeholder. You must then scroll up or down by at least 1 pixel so the image will load.

Before I start figuring out some cheesy hack that makes certain containers scrollUp or scrollDown by 1 pixel, I thought I'd ask: There must be some way to tell lazyload to comprehend more than just scrolling action? As soon as the image comes into view (by however means) the image should load. Or whatever, I'd go for any creative solution, even if it's a bit cheesy.

Comment: I've tried searching for "user:Stephen hasaccepted:0" to find 'unaccepted' posts but that doesn't work. If there's a way that I can quickly do this (without studying the forum rules all day) I'm all ears.

Comment: There is no need to search, go to your profile page and you we'll see all the questions that you have asked so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies if I've misunderstood your request, but I believe there are a couple of lazyload options you can set to work in the instance (I think) you're describing:

The first is for implementations like a horizontal scrolling div, where you have to tell lazyload to work on said div, like so:

```
$("img.needstoload").lazyload({         
     container: $("#scrollydivid")
});
```

There's also the 'skip_invisible' parameter, which you may need to set to false, as lazyload ignores invisible images by default (untill you scroll vertically, when it re-checks images to see if any need to be loaded)...

Comment: Alright I tried setting skip_invisible to false but it didn't make a difference. It seems like it should, though. I'll try to find a way to use ScrollTo to scroll up or down by 1px. I'm the king of cheesy solutions.

Comment: The other option would be to have the images that are causing the problem loaded without going through lazyload (i.e. simply not have the class of image lazyload is targeting on the hidden ones, so they'll load no matter what). That said, whether that's a viable solution or not depends on how many images there are, how big they are, and how important bandwidth usage is to you...

Comment: You're right I'll probably have to skip lazyloading for this particular div section. It never dawned on me to just surrender lazyloading. :)